# Object reference is not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to pass a value from DetailsView to FormView but I always get an error: Object reference is not set to an instance of an object. Somehow it did pass a value and I could still perform an insert. Its my first time programming in C#. Any hep would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Here I've attached a code behind. I think the prob here is that I dont have a null check so how can I add a null check?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class BookLending : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert && FormView1.Fin != null) 
            {
                TextBox bookid = FormView1.FindControl("bookidTextBox") as TextBox;
                bookid.Text = ((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["bookid"].ToString();
            }
            {
                TextBox employee = FormView1.FindControl("EmployeeIDTextBox") as TextBox;
                employee.Text = ((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["EmployeeID"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Sorry its my first time programming so how can I 'throw an exception'. I've just started two months ago but still couldnt get it. Looks like I still have a long way to go. Oh and pardon for my english.

Comment: Press F5 to debug. Then when the `FormView1` is databound, wait until a line is highlighted in yellow--meaning, an exception is thrown there.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks sir! Here's the code with the highlighted yellow: bookid.Text = ((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["bookid"].ToString();

Comment: As in my answer, can you see if `((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["bookid"]` is null? Do a quick watch and check. If it is null, then `ToString()` is throwing the exception and you should put your null check around that. Next step would be to determine if your `bookid` is a valid index of `DataRowView`. You can also check if you are casting `DetailsView1.DataItem` to `DataRowView` properly.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks again sir! Looks like 2 people doesnt like my post. I almost lost my hope anyway I'll try it right away.

Comment: Ok, that should help solve your problem. If it does, I would appreciate if you accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few places you can check for null.

1) If your cast is incorrect:

```
TextBox bookid = FormView1.FindControl("bookidTextBox") as TextBox;
if (bookid != null)
    bookid.Text = ((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["bookid"].ToString();

TextBox employee = FormView1.FindControl("EmployeeIDTextBox") as TextBox;
if (employee != null)
    employee.Text = ((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["EmployeeID"].ToString();
```

2) If the controls don't have values, `ToString()` will also throw the object null reference exception:

```
((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["bookid"] != null
((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["EmployeeID"] != null
```

In which line of your code is the exception thrown?

Answer (score 2):

As is a soft cast, so at some point it's not able to cast.  Perhaps try using explicit casting or step through the code to find out if FindControl is returning a a control.

Answer (score 0):

Thread is old, but i ran into this error when i was binding a dropdownlist selected value in a formview's itemtemplate and edititemtemplete.  I solved this by putting the code inside a try catch statement.